# Using jquery element in haml condition

Tags: jquery, haml, conditional-statements

I'm stuck on this small detail for few hours already, so please...
I am trying to fadeout an element if a different element is empty.
I am inside a '.js.haml' file.

I tried this

```
- if($("#task-list-open").is(':empty')) 
  $("#open-task-container").fadeOut("slow");
```

and it seems that the '$' in the first line is unexpected and raises a compile error.

The "#open-task-container" has the "#task-list-open" in it,
and I want to hide the whole 'container' if the 'list' is empty.

The html looks like this (I have simplified it):

```
<div id="open-task-container">
  <table class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" />
  <div id="task-list-open">
    <div id="task_1" class="task" />
    <div id="task_4" class="task" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this: `var lst = $("#task-list-open"); if (lst.is(':empty')) $("#open-task-container").fadeOut("slow");`

Comment: thanks for answering, for some reason the ':empty' didnt work, maybe its my ruby version ('3.0.10'). I have used Baszz's '.length' insted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var isEmpty = ($("#task-list-open div").length <= 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just dont understand when should I use '- if' and when just 'if', when writing haml. My initial tries didnt work because the '- if' didnt accept any variables.

Comment: You should always use `-if`, without the leading `-` if will just render as "if" in plain text.

Comment: Can you underrrstand why the '-if' doesnt recognize variables that were defined in a line just above it, and why it doesnt allow the '$' sign?